# Wordpress shortcode tabs, what's wrong?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to do a very simple shortcode tabs with my small developpment knowledge.

I have a problem with my shortcode. When I click on other tabs, the content doesn't change, I don't know why :/

Can you tell me what's wrong ?

The HTML version which works:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="pill"><img class="img-nav-pills" src="#" /> Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1" data-toggle="pill"><img class="img-nav-pills" src="#" /> Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2" data-toggle="pill"><img class="img-nav-pills" src="#" /> Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">Content 1</div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">Content 2</div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

The code I wrote:

The shortcode code:

```
[tab_menu_skeleton]
[tab_menu tab_class="active" tab_id="1" tab_img="https://i.imgur.com/2AGKegq.png"]test[/tab_menu]
[tab_menu tab_class="" tab_id="2" tab_img="https://i.imgur.com/2AGKegq.png"]test2[/tab_menu]
[/tab_menu_skeleton][tab_content_skeleton]
[tab_content tab_content_active="in active" tab_content_id="1"]texte 1[/tab_content]
[tab_content tab_content_active="" tab_content_id="2"]texte 2[/tab_content]
[/tab_content_skeleton]
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the first row of your shortcode code:

Instead of this: `[tab_menu_skeletone]`

Use this: `[tab_menu_skeleton]`

Comment: Yes, It's a mistake on the copy / paste here ^^ But this is not the essence of the problem :)

Comment: You have a closing `</nav>` tag in your PHP but not an opening one.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my message. I have been on since yesterday, I did a lot of tests, suddenly I created more mistakes than necessary.

Comment: I think in the PHP the `href` attr of the `<a>` nested in the `<li>` should be the id of the target `<div>` prefixed with a #, and the target `<div>` should not start with a #.